# Accessing third table auto generated by entity framework when using many-to-many in models

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, blazor

When a many-to-many relation is defined within models, a third table is auto created by Entity framework. I am able to see this table within the database but I am not sure how I would access it's data. The third table is *ApplicationUserProject* defining a relationship between *Projects* and *Users*

How might access this table and it's data? Thanks in advance

### Third generated table

[image]

Comment: Why do you need access to this table? If you really need that, you have to define entity which will be mapped to this table. Everything in documentation [Many-to-many UsingEntity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many)

Comment: I was looking to grab all the users who are associated to a specific project using the projectID. When I try to retrieve all the users from the Project table as a list using include()..., the value just returned as null so im not sure how to perform such an operation. Thought accessing the third table would be best @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case you do not need access to intermediate table.

```cs
var query = context.Users
  .Where(u => u.Projects.Any(p => p.Id == projectId));
```

Comment: Thanks so much! How did you know to query the table like this? Looking to learn more